# Is who is richer game possible with bitcoin script?

Tags: script

With Bitcoin script, is it possible to construct a timelocked address X in such a way that:

- Players A and B (maybe more players) can send bitcoin to this address;
- When the timelock expires,the player **that had sent more bitcoin to address X** can withdraw all bitcoin to himself;
- If deposits where equal, then whoever is first - withdraws;
  ?

Comment: There's a few misunderstandings in your question. You don't construct timelocked addresses, you can construct time-locked transaction outputs. Each payment a player makes to an address results in a different transaction output - so each would need a timelock. There is no way to cross reference information from different transaction outputs in bitcoin script, nor can the script have access to the amount.

Comment: Thanks for clarification!

Comment: I guess this: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/23780/is-there-any-way-to-send-an-output-to-a-script-which-can-then-only-be-sent-to-on?rq=1 answers my question as well.